# MS Word 2016 Macro Regex Replace

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word, office365

I am trying to code a macro using `Regex` and my pattern is `\(\bTopic \d+\b\)` and macro should remove **(Topic 1)** and **(Topic 2)** from all questions in the whole document, but my macro code is not working. Thanks for your help.

**Input:**

QUESTION NO: 1 (Topic 1)

QUESTION NO: 15 (Topic 2)

**Result should be**

QUESTION NO: 1

QUESTION NO: 15

**Macro Code**

```
Sub RemoveQuestionTopic()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "\(\bTopic \d+\b\)"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regexp syntax differs from normal regexp. If you replace your expression with this:

```
.Text = "\(Topic ([0-9]@>)\)"
```

you will get the expected result. No need to use VBScript.Regexp in this case.

Comment: Certainly better solution than mine. +1. Can you also provide some link for reference from where I can learn more about word regexp syntax?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/86397/wildcards-in-word contains a lot of information and good links

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked like a charm. Since this is a better solution as @Gurman also agreed. I am marking this one the right answer. Thanks again

Comment: You could reduce that further, to: .Text = "\(Topic [0-9]@\)". For more on *wildcards* in Word, see: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm And, if the number following 'Topic' is only ever a single digit, you don't even need *wildcards* - just (Topic ^#).

Comment: Forum swallows backslashes - .Text = "\\(Topic [0-9]@\\)"

Answer (score 1):

The Find functionality provide only a very limited support to the regular expressions. You need to use `VBScript.Regexp` as shown below.

Try this Code:

```
Sub RemoveQuestionTopic()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    strReplacementText = "++__++"
    ActiveDocument.Select
    Set objReg = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
    objReg.Pattern = "\s*\(Topic\s*\d+\)"
    objReg.Global = True
    Selection.Text = objReg.Replace(Selection.Text, strReplacementText)

    With Selection.Find
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Text = strReplacementText
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zMGSnq/1)**